# Not able to plot summation graph in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot a summation graph with throughput(x) against Rmax

[image]

```
v = 8;
Q = 4;
f = 1;
OH = 0.14;
u = 1;
BW = 10*10^-6;
PRB = 1;
Rmax = 490/1024;
j=1;
Ts = (10^-3)/(14*(2^u));
N =1;

syms j
x = (10^-6) * symsum( v * Q * f * Rmax * (( N * 12 )/ Ts ) * ( 1 - OH ) , j , 1 , 1);

figure
plot(Rmax, double(x));
title('Throughput vs Rmax')
xlabel('Throughput')
ylabel('Rmax')
grid minor
```

I am trying to plot the summation of x against Rmax, but the plot is returning an empty graphs

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate question but can't find any examples right now. `Rmax` is a scalar value, so you are plotting a single point. The default `plot` linestyle does not have a marker style so you are plotting a line with no length. Make `Rmax` an array or use a `'.'` marker style in the call to `plot`

Comment: I'm interested in this solution as well. Can you give an example?